# I have added few tables in BI engine in big query. How can I be sure that it using BI engine to return result and not BIG query?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bi-engine

Even after that when I am querying the query is not utilizing BI engine and returns as BI engine mode as NULL.
I am using the below query to check the output :

```
SELECT
  creation_time,
  job_id,
  bi_engine_statistics
FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE
  creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  AND job_type = "QUERY"
  -- and job_id = 'XXXXXXXX'
  order by creation_time DESC;
```

Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There may be three reasons for that behavior:

- Make sure that BI Engine reservation is created in project that issues the query. For example, job submitted in 'my_connection_project123' with SQL
  `SELECT * FROM my_data_project.dataset1.table1` will not use BI Engine reservation from 'my_data_project'. Instead, BI Engine reservation should be configured in 'my_connection_project123'.
- Make sure that location for BI Engine Reservation is exactly the same as job location. For example, creating BI Reservation in "US" multi-region will not accelerate jobs issued in "us-east1" and vice versa. See [BigQuery locations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations) page for details.
- After creating BI Engine reservation, it may take several seconds for changes to take effect. Previously, it was taking minutes and may have been a bigger issue.

Hope that helps